# How can I use nested [] to replace a if-then-fi ? ("[: -f: binary operator expected")

Tags: bash, bashrc

In my .bashrc file I have:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then . /etc/bash_completion; fi
```

I wanted to use `[]` around it instead of `if then fi`

I already have

```
[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && source ~/.bash_aliases
[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -ge 4 ] && shopt -s autocd
[ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ] && source ~/.git-completion.bash
```

so I thought maybe I could use

```
[ [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && [! shopt -oq posix] ] && . /etc/bash_completion
```

but I get

```
-bash: [: -f: binary operator expected
```

Comment: `[ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix && . /etc/bash_completion`

Comment: Please post, my fellow New Englander ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just chain `&&`'s, no need to *nest* conditionals here:

```
[ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix && . /etc/bash_completion
```

works.

Answer (score 3):

You mix up two commands. `[` is not eqivalent to `if`. `[` is equivalent to `test`.

`if` is not even a simple command but a reserved word (like `[[`), part of a control structure. `if ... then ... else ... fi` is nearly eqivalent to `... && { ...; true; } || { ... }`